# My blu ray device can read but can't write blu-ray or DVD's

Tags: dvd, blu-ray, cd

my blu ray device can read media but is unable to write to media. I still haven't tested it with CD's. I also have no Blu rays with any data on them to test it out. However it is capable of reading DVD's. So far I have tried to write to a BD-r and a DVD media.
Update here is my k3b error log:
http://pastebin.com/fzqsu3Y0

Comment: And what exactly might that “blu ray device” be? Please update your question with its make and model.

Comment: It is a no name device, but my laptop recognises it as MATSHITA BD-CMB UJ-120. If it doesn't write then I was cheated by the seller.

Comment: [This thing](https://www.amazon.com/UJ-120-PANASONIC/dp/B001QA4TQO)? It can only write DVDs/CDs. It can read BD. Seeing how all Google turns up are problem reports and whatnot, it seems to be a bad model anyway. // Please provide further details on how exactly burning a DVD would fail.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question and added my error log.

Comment: For DVD+R, try manually setting a lower write speed, e.g. 4x. As mentioned by others though, you won't be able to burn Blu-Ray discs.

Comment: Well. I guess for BD writing I will either have to sell this device to someone else or return it and buy another one. I might keep it only if I get DVD burning working.

Answer (score 0):

The drive only annouces to support profile BD-ROM, but not BD-R or BD-RE.
Its name "BD-CMB" reminds of "Combo drive", an old euphemism for burning
not all kinds of writable media which it can read.

I still own a LG "BDDVDRW GGC-H20" which i once bought because it was
cheaper than all BD-ROM drives and one can never have enough DVD burners.
It issues about the same profile list as your drive.

The DVD burning run died because of a bad relation between drive and
medium. Power calibration area is a writable test area on the medium
where the drive can make read-write experiments to find the best settings
for the laser power. The drive found it was too bad to process further.